# Tomcat Client Deployer error (JarScannerCallback)

Tags: tomcat, client, noclassdeffounderror

Maybe there is a huge thing I missed, but I am having an issue with Tomcat Client Deployer.  I installed Ant as indicated (set the environment veriables Path, JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME).  It works, but when I try to "compile" my web appliation, I get a NoClassDefFoundException on JarScannerCallback.  Any one has an idea on why this is happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat libs need to be in the ant & jasper classpath. Try insert following lines in your build.xml. First declare a property with the valid path to your tomcat install directory:

```
<property name="tomcatdistro" value="/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.16"/>
```

...then extend deployer.classpath as follows:

```
<path id="deployer.classpath">
  ...
  <fileset dir="${tomcatdistro}/lib">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>
```

...and javac:

```
<javac destdir="${webapp.path}/WEB-INF/classes"...
  ...
  <classpath>
    ...
    <fileset dir="${tomcatdistro}/lib">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </classpath>
</javac>
```

that's it.